# New robot 3.1.2 does not support test name with '[1]' sequence

Tags: robotframework

When launching robot command : robot -t a[1]Test toto.robot, I have error message :
[ ERROR ] Suite 'toto' contains no tests matching name 'a[1]Test'.
My robot file is as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
*** Test Cases ***
a[1]Test
    dated log           Test
```

I tried with/without '', or "", or by escaping [ and ] with \, but is lead to the same. But same command with robot 3.0.4 is OK on same file
So, it seems new robot (3.1.2) is not supporting 'a[1]Test' test name

1. is it a known bug ?
2. how to workaround it

Comment: You should open an issue at GitHub, Robot Framework.

Comment: Can you provide link to any documentation (3.0.4) where it is specified how to use test names with [1] sequence? I tried but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

```
robot -t a[[]1[]]Test
```

Test Names should not include wild-card (regex-style) characters, such as square brackets, because they are interpreted as meta-characters.  See [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#wildcards)

Your command-line example, running a `-t`  (or -i, or -e) means you are specifying a regex.  `robot -t a[1]Test` would match the name `a1Test` and only that name.

But I recommend avoiding "*", "[" and "?" in the test name itself.

Comment: Yes, I tried escaping with \ on the command line, but it lead to the same
Here this is an exemple, but all our test cases should begin by '[x]...' to map on rules of QC (Quality Center : Hewlett Packard tool to manage test suites and their results in a DB)
Now, : robot -t a?1?Test is matching the run of this test case

Comment: OK, then try `[[]` which the Documentation claims is the escape for square bracket.    Which, in your case, would look like this:  `robot -t a[[]1[]]Test`

Comment: If you ever switch to TestRail (instead of QC), the naming convention is kinder:  `[Tags]    test_case_id=C123456`   corresponding to the TestRail TC 123456.  You can then upload results from Robot into TestRail using a Python tool [such as this one I found](https://github.com/ATEME/robotframework-testrail) or call the TestRail API yourself.